# Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

Tags: c#

So this is my first C# program and I am trying to make a basic program that will calculate the area of a circle with a UI. I am using Windows Forms in Visual Studio.

This is what I have so far

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const double pi = 3.14159;
        double r;
        double areaCircle = pi * r * r;
    }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.text = r
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          outputBox.Text = areaCircle

        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run it I get errors at each object stating "Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct" I'm sure it's probably a total bonehead thing I'm doing wrong, but can someone please help?

Comment: You have a stray closing brace before `public Form1()`. I imagine Visual Studio is showing you a red squiggly line somewhere in that area?

Comment: You are missing quite a few semi colons at a first glance. It wont compile.

Comment: here is a [C# Tutorial for Beginners](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp) click on this link and book mark it for future references until you become more proficient at the language.. pay close attention to the syntax

Comment: Please do not dramatically alter the question. It invalidates the answers and defeats the purpose of this site's Q&A format. If you have a new question, use the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `}` on the line after `double areaCircle = pi * r * r;` that shouldn't be there.

You're prematurely ending the definition of the class when you clearly aren't finished defining it.

Comment: Yes this corrected the first of several errors - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your class with the below. You will need to unwire the textboxchanged event.

i.e.

```
   using statements...

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
    <remove your code and place the code below here>
    }

     public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            const double pi = 3.14159;

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                double radius;
                double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out radius);
                var area = pi * radius * radius;
                outputBox.Text = string.Format("{0}", area);
            }

        }
```

Check that you have the following controls on the form: textBox1 (TextBox), outputBox (TextBox), button1 (Button). In the designer, click on button1, go to its properties, click the little lightning bolt icon to show events and make sure it is wired to button1_Click. Double click the button, make sure Visual Studio takes you to the code in the code behind file for button1_Click. Run the app. Type a number in to the textbox1 TextBox and then click on button1. Your result (the area) should display in outputBox. Check your spelling too, the code is case sensitive.

Comment: Ok I have it where the code will execute, however I can't show output.

Comment: Updated with more items to check.

Comment: Ok, I got it running properly. I'm not sure how to submit the answer with the functioning code, but if someone will unlock this question I may be able to.

Comment: You should have an option just to mark my answer as a solution or you may be able to just click the up arrow next to my post.